# SQL Exception during runtime

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I got a `SqlException` at runtime.

```
<add name="ConnStr" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
     connectionString="Password=123;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=test;Data Source=test" />
```

When I tried to connect at runtime, I get this error

Kindly help me in fixing it

Comment: Please add exception message and calling code.

Comment: you don't need calling code to see what this error is it's in how the connection string has been defined based on a quick glance please show the exact error

Comment: Your `Data Source` parameter is set to "test" - is that the actual network name of the server? See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.datasource(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: `Persist Security Info=True` this is not needed and if so set it to false your problem is in the connection string as I have stated before

Comment: @C.Evenhuis Its the actual network name it is a server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like that

```
<add name="connstr" 
     connectionString="Data Source=test;Initial catalog=test;User=sa;Password=123" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`
```

Comment: Could you explain what you changed and why this would work? That way someone could learn something instead of simply copy pasting.

Comment: Actually that would work `C.Evenhuis` I just tested it on my server passing in the credentials that I need to connect to a database and it works just fine even doing something like this works for me as well `    <add name="dbconn" connectionString="server=VLD210;database=TestDB_DEV;uid=TstAdmin;pwd=!@xx123"/>`

Comment: i changed the order of the connection string values, since its only 1 row try it out, could might help, this line i posted i saw it on a working website i searched in google and i changed it with the values u have in your question, hopefully it works

Comment: @DJKRAZE I didn't say it would not work, I just see _some_ differences between the original and this one, but didn't see which one was wrong and/or why. Shiro thanks for the explanation

Comment: just a note here:  when i tried to connect with php on my database from a .php file on my server, i couldnt. i had to go to my cPanel and add my server IP on the whitelist (accepted IP's). , basically im trying to say that you have to manually add your accepted IP's through your cPanel if you dont know that already... for example if you had a C# app on your computer that accessed your database, you have to add your computers IP address to the whitelist, but you probably know this already...

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you have kept the **Initial Catalog** and **Data Source** both as test. Are you sure that your server name and data base name is test? Please find the difference below.

1. `Data Source` is the name of server you want to interact with, If its a local server you can put dot(.) sign so that all the databases of this server will be available to you. If its on other server put the IP address or the name of the server, make sure its connected via network.
2. `Initial catalog` is the name of the database you want to work with that is available on the server you have mentioned in `Data Source` attribute.

So this for example:

```
<add name="SampleConnectionString" 
 connectionString="Data Source=test;Initial catalog=test;User=sa;Password=123" 
 providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`
```

looks at the data source that is pointing to `.` which means I want to connect to my local SQL Server. `Initial Catalog` is `SampleDataBase` which is the database on my local SQL Server instance.

Please let me know if it resolves the issue.

Comment: @hari_Cheers : You got the solution? If you still have problem please let us know else please mark it as solution.